# how to pass textarea id into jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

in my web form,i am having Textarea and link button that shows pop up message that contains cursor position if i placed my cursor in that text area
below is the following code ., but it is not displaying anything

```
<textarea id="msgtxt" runat="server">the text is an example</textarea>  
<a href="#" onclick="alert( $('#msgtxt').getCursorPosition() );  
return false;">getCursorPosition</a>
```

my jquery function is

```
(function($, undefined) {  
$.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {  
var el = $(this).get(0);  
var pos = 0;  
if ('selectionStart' in el) {  
pos = el.selectionStart;  
} else if ('selection' in document) {  
el.focus();  
var Sel = document.selection.createRange();  
var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;  
Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);  
pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;  
}  
   return pos;  
}  
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` you give your textarea isn't, by default, the `id` it has on the client. The `id` for it on the client is auto-generated by ASP.net. You can find out what it is using the [`ClientID` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So instead of `$('#msgbox')`, you need to pass in the actual client ID via `$('#<%=msgbox.ClientID%>')`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert( $('#<%=msgbox.ClientID%>').getCursorPosition() );  
return false;">getCursorPosition</a>
```

Alternately, you can use [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the control to tell ASP.net to use the `id` as the client-side ID:

```
yourControlInstance.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
```

(There are other modes as well, see MSDN for details.)

Answer (score 0):

Change to this.

**html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert( getCursorPosition(this) );
```

**js**

```
(function($, undefined) {  
$.fn.getCursorPosition = function(obj) { 
var txtAreaValue = $(obj).prev("input").val(); //add this
var el = $(this).get(0);  
var pos = 0;  
if ('selectionStart' in el) {  
pos = el.selectionStart;  
} else if ('selection' in document) {  
el.focus();  
var Sel = document.selection.createRange();  
var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;  
Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);  
pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;  
}  
   return pos;  
}  
})(jQuery);
```

In this answer i pass the element in the js function and after i find textArea value with a simple jquery selector.